# Finding equivalent angles using transversal

Tags: geometry, angle

On this free body diagram, how am I able to see that the two angles $\alpha$ are equivalent?

[image]

I have read about [transversals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversal_(geometry)), but I still can't see on this diagram.

Comment: Because $F_1$ is vertical, it makes a right angle with the horizontal line at the bottom. That makes the angle $\beta = 90° - \alpha$ between the slope and $F_1$. The longer dotted line is perpendicular to the slope, so the angle opposite upper $\alpha$ is $\beta$, which makes the two $\alpha$'s equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

If the two sides of an angle are perpendicular to the sides of another angle, then the angles are either equal or supplementary.
[image]